# Why does my action method with default parameters cause a 404?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got a WebApi action method that does this:

```
Public Function GetSomething(Id As Integer, Optional SomeValue As Integer = 0) As HttpResponseMessage
```

I have the standard route in place:

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute _
    (
        "DefaultWebApi",
        "api/{controller}/{action}"
    )
```

If I call my route specifying `Id` **AND** `SomeValue`, it works fine:

```
/api/MyController/GetSomething?Id=123&SomeValue=345
```

But if I don't specify `SomeValue`, I get a 404:

```
/api/MyController/GetSomething?Id=123
```

I don't understand this at all, because `SomeValue` is Optional.  If I don't specify it, I would expect the framework to call my method and just pass the default value, and I think this is what MVC (not WebApi) does.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm...I am unable to repro your scenario...which version of Web API are you using?

Comment: Are you saying this just works for you?  I'm not sure how you check the version, but the version of my System.Web.Http file is 5.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was totally unrelated, although I'm still puzzled why WebApi didn't do the right thing.  The code that created my url was accidentally adding an extra `&` character, so my url was actually this:

```
/api/MyController/GetSomething?Id=123&
```

When I removed this extra `&`, the default parameter worked again.

I don't really get why that breaks the default parameter mechanism in WebApi though.